# Tomcat-6: manager for specific host

Tags: linux, tomcat, virtualhost, shared-hosting, tomcat6

I have Linux server with one Tomcat-6 installation and many hosts. All hosts are configured in /etc/tomcat/server.xml , each host points to different folder and webapps folder. Is there any way to give access to each hosts owner to deploy/redeploy/etc all apps in specific hosts folder? I went thru all Tomcat configuration manual and didn't find anything about this. Manager app is always showing all web-applications.

Comment: I also have several vhosts, however in different folder, using appBase="/home/...". I can't find a way to access the manager in vhosts - http://vhost/manager shows 404. But I can see it being deployed in the log.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't got an environment here with virtual hosts set up to try this on but I think if you deploy a separate instance of the manager to each virtual host directory then it may restrict it successfully.

*source: http://old.nabble.com/Tomcat-6.0.29,-Manager-App,-multiple-virtual-hosts-td29907541.html*